# Scala code will not pick up implicit class instance

Tags: scala, implicit

Why is the implicit not being picked up automatically??
implicit class is not picked up by default as evidence in the code below.

```
object temp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    case class Foo(str: String)

    trait Special[A] {
      def getStr: String
    }

    implicit class SpecialFoo(x: Foo) extends Special[Foo] {
      def getStr = x.str
    }

    /* For the above SpecialFoo implicit class, I think the following is replaced by the compiler:
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       class SpecialFooClass(x: Foo) {
         def getStr: String = x.str
       }
       implicit def specialFooFunction(x: Foo): SpecialFooClass = new SpecialFooClass(x);
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    def specialFunction[T: Special](thing: T): String = implicitly[Special[T]].getStr;

    // val wrapped = specialFunction(Foo("hi")) // Will not pick up the implicit SpecialFoo class, why??

    val foo = Foo("hi")
    val wrapped1: String = specialFunction(foo)(SpecialFoo(foo)) // But giving the evidence explicitly works!

    println(wrapped1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post real code, not images of code. This text can't be copy/pasted into an IDE editor for testing/evaluation.

Comment: Sorry, added the code verbatim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up two concepts here.

On one hand, there is implicit *conversion*, which means the compiler will convert a value of type `Foo` into a value of type `Special[Foo]` whenever it needs to. That's indeed what your `implicit class` declares.

On the other hand, the

```
def specialFunction[T: Special](thing: T): String
```

is a shortcut for

```
def specialFunction[T](thing: T)(implicit ev: Special[T]): String
```

This means the `specialFunction` method takes two arguments. The second argument is implicit, which means that if you don't pass it explicitly, the compiler will try to find it in the implicit scope. However, here you *don't* have an implicit `Special[Foo]` in scope. What you have is an implicit way to convert `Foo` into `Special[Foo]`.

The pattern you're trying to use here is very common, but it's usually achieved in another way:

```
  trait Special[A] {
    def getStr(a: A): String
  }

  case class Foo(str: String)
  object Foo {
    implicit val special: Special[Foo] = new Special[Foo] {
      override def getStr(a: Foo) = a.str
    }
  }

  def specialFunction[T: Special](thing: T): String = 
    implicitly[Special[T]].getStr(thing)

  val foo = Foo("hi")
  println(specialFunction(foo))
```

Here, we don't wrap `Foo` into `Special[Foo]`, but instead treat `Special[A]` as a separate entity that knows how to extract a `String` from an `A`.

Note: If you're using Scala 2.12, you can express `val special` in a very concise way thanks to support for single abstract method (traits or abstract classes that only consist of a single abstract method, like `Special[A]` only has `getStr`):

`implicit val special: Special[Foo] = _.str`

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer.
Replacing 'implicit val special: Special[Foo] = new Special[Foo] { override def getStr(a: Foo) = a.str }' with 'implicit val special: Special[Foo] = _.str', I get a an error "Missing parameter type".
If I understand you correctly, what I need is an implicit instance of Special[Foo], which is missing. What I have is a function that converts Foo into Special[Foo], but I guess that is not considered while matching the implicit. As 'bottaio' has indicated I declare specialFunction to have implicit function parameter, instead of implicit instance parameter.

Comment: Using the shorthand for `implicit val special: Special[Foo] = _.str` should work if you're using Scala 2.12. You're right about `ev: T => Special[T]` not being the same as `ev: Special[T]`. The first one will allow your original idea to work, as bottaio explained. However, I personally find my solution more elegant. I guess it's a matter of taste!

Answer (score 2):

Although @francoisr answer is a valid answer it seems like you would like to be able to pass an object to a method that implements `Special[A]` interface. Your code will compile for the following definition of `specialFunction`.

```
def specialFunction[T](thing: T)(implicit toSpecial: T => Special[T]): String = thing.getStr
```

This expresses your need to convert type `T` to a `Special[T]` and thus you are able to call `.getStr` method.

Comment: Note that the `toSpecial` is often declared as `implicit ev: T <:< Special[T]` in many codebases. The `<:<` class can be found in `scala.Predef` which is available anywhere.

Comment: Also note that defining `FooSpecial` as an `implicit class` and using this solution will sometimes lead to a useless object allocation being done to wrap `Foo` when you call `foo.getStr` (even if `FooSpecial` extends `AnyVal`).

Comment: Thank you. Did not know that one could give an implicit function as the last parameter.

Comment: So my implicit function changes 
From:
def specialFunction[T](thing: T)(implicit evidence: Special[T]): String = evidence.getStr

To:
def specialFunction[T](thing: T)(implicit evidence: T => Special[T]): String = thing.getStr
And my code compiles and works (except for useless object creation as 'francoisr' has pointed out). In the first case I access getStr on evidence and in the second case I access it on thing. Any thoughts why this is? I suppose that in first case evidence object is guaranteed to be Special[Foo] but in the second case how is thing guaranteed to have getStr?

Comment: In the case where you take a function, `thing` still does not have `getStr`, but `thing` is implicitly converted to a `Special[Foo]` which does have `getStr`. You can even make this conversion more explicit using `toSpecial(thing).getStr` instead.